# How to make this menu drop down or like accordion

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, sidebar

I am using sitesmile auction theme. [Here](http://eliteauct.com/) is my working site. In home page there is a sidebar saying "Browse by Categories". I want to make this menu as drop down or like accordion. Whenever the user hover on the parent category, the sub category will appear.

As it is the category of Custom Post Type, I can't figure that out.

Here is an example, how I want mine:
[image: Menu image]

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like that list is in your sidebar anymore, but I did find it on your "Show All Categories" page. You can accomplish the accordion effect either with CSS or a combination of CSS + jQuery; here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/angelique/cZDWr/) example to get you started. As this is a display issue, it doesn't matter if they are normal pages or custom post types. :)